# Finding $\lim\limits_{x→\frac π4} \frac{\tan(4x)}{\sin(2x)-1}$

Tags: limits

I have a problem here. I try a lot of methods like make it $\dfrac{\sin2x}{2x}$ but I did not solve it. Please, if someone have just an idea about a method to solve it I will be thankful.

Answer (score 1):

Set $\dfrac\pi4-x=y$

$$\lim_{x\to\frac\pi4}\dfrac{\tan4x}{\sin2x-1}=\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac{\tan4y}{1-\cos2y}=\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac{1+\cos2y}{\cos4y}\cdot\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac{\sin4y}{4y}\cdot\left(\dfrac{2y}{\sin2y}\right)^2\cdot\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac1 y$$

Now what can say about the existence of the following limit?

$\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac1 y$

Comment: +oo I think ...

Comment: @FatimaAbou, $$\lim_{y\to0^-}\dfrac1y=?$$

Comment: -00 OK I got it it has two solution in lim0- = -oo and in lim0+ = +OK

Comment: +00 thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Set $y=\pi/2-2x$, so $2x=\pi/2-y$ and
\begin{align}
\tan4x&=\tan(\pi-2y)=-\tan2y \\[4px]
\sin2x&=\cos y
\end{align}
If $x\to\pi/4$, then $y\to0$, so your limit becomes
$$
\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\tan2y}{1-\cos y}=
\lim_{y\to0}\frac{2\sin y}{1-\cos y}\frac{\cos y}{\cos2y}
$$
What do you know about
$$
\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\sin y}{y}
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\lim_{y\to0}\frac{1-\cos y}{y}
$$
which are very basic limits?

Comment: Siny/y=1 and lim0 of (1-cosy)\y=1\2

Comment: Siny/y=1 and lim0 of (1-cosy)\y=1\2

Comment: @FatimaAbou No, the latter is $0$ (positive from the right and negative from the left).